# Is there a way to read a JSON-File using a String in TypeScript?

Tags: json, typescript

I'm doing the frontend for a project im working in with a friend and I am struggeling with the language-switch at the moment.
I planned to make a function, which I can call with an Attribute 'id' to read a text from a JSON-File (See pictures bellow for better info). However im struggeling here, because obveously I cant just return `data.id`. I can't find something on the internet and was wondering if someone here could help me.

Goal is, that I can call `t(navigation.xyz)` from any point in the applicationand will receive the right text.

```js
import * as dataEn from "./en.json";
import * as dataDe from "./de.json";

import {ELanguage} from "../enums/OGFE-Enums";

function t(id: string): string {
    let language: ELanguage = ELanguage.ENGLISH;

    id = "navigation.games";

    if (language === ELanguage.ENGLISH) {
        return dataEn?.;
    } else {
        return dataDe.id;
    }
}
```

JSON:

```json
{
  "navigation": {
    "games": "Games",
    "about-us": "About us",
    "installation-guide": "Installation Guide",
    "release-notes": "Release notes",
    "qaa": "Q&A"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to keep your json in a .js file and export as a const like this:

**dataEn.js**

```js
export dataEn
{
  // your json here...
}
```

and then import it as:

```js
import dataEn from '../dataEn.js'
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).